# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle:2.2.0-beta01

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-lifecycle, androidx

I'm having issues with the `build.gradle` file, specially the module `'android.x.lifecycle'`.

I have the following error

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle:2.2.0-beta01
This is the last version of androidx.lifecycle
```

I don't know if it a syntax error

This is the build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flixarts.ar.englishnow"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle:2.2.0-beta01'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle:2.2.0-beta01
```

with one of these:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0-beta01" 
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.2.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.2.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0-beta01"
```

More info about Lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).

Also:

- change `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3` to `androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1` since you are using androidx library
- you are adding `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` thrice
- remove the support library: `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'`
- remove the `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'` and `buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'`(don't use `=` in any case). You can specify `buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"` in the `android` block or just omit it and gradle will automatically use the latest version according to the `targetSdkVersion` specified

Comment: the `buildToolsVersion` is also duplicate and should be removed altogether and `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3` is not androidx either ...

Comment: `buildToolsVersion` could be removed altogether, then it will automatically use the latest version according to the `targetSdkVersion` specified (it wasn't always alike that).

Comment: Not only, `buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'` is wrong in any case  for the use of `=`